# Is it safe to leave live wires in a fan assembly?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I had an electrician install a new bathroom ventilator fan in my wall. This is connected to the overhead lights in the bathroom and runs on a timer. Unfortunately the fan is faulty and can't be allowed to run.

I've removed the three wires leading into the fan and cut them straight across. Is this a safe enough way to leave things? Is there any risk of electrical problems/fire?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As everything is covered in plastic and separated there is no fire danger. I like putting a wire nut or electrical tape over cut wires even if not energized as a good practice but . You should be ok with your concerns.

Comment: I've covered the wire ends each with electrical tape and remounted the fan cover. Is it safe to leave like this on a semi long term basis?

Comment: It will be fine covered with tape and even code compliant as you plan to repair in the future so that wire is not abandoned (normally temporary repairs  are within 90 days) but in this case it will be fine inside the plastic cover with tape on the ends.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not safe. Those wires should be disconnect where they originate, at the overhead lights. If a new fan is to be installed, the proper electrical box should be installed as these wires seem to come right through the drywall ceiling. With the power off, fold each wire over and tape with electrical tape until you can disconnect them from the light fixture.

Comment: Can you elaborate why it is not safe, and what my concerns should be? The wires do indeed come straight through the drywall. I've covered each with electrical tape now, but I do anticipate having to leave them in this state for some unknown length of time.

Comment: I was under the impression you were going to remove the fan. If it stays and you replaced the cover and taped and separated the wires you should be ok.

Comment: Yes, I have covered each of the wire ends with electrical tape, maintained separation between them, and replaced the cover. I don't intend to remove the fan or make any other changes. Just wanted to make sure I am not putting my flat at risk of fire. Thanks.

Comment: Don't understand the DV after all this time.